# How to print contents on webpage from RESTful web service

Tags: node.js, rest, express, pug

I am using a RESTful web service to make a to do list app. I am able to make a GET request and retrieve all of my todos but I don't know how to print them onto my webpage.

Here is the part responsible for making the GET request:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    request({
    url: url, //URL to hit
    qs: {from: 'blog example', time: +new Date()}, //Query string data
    method: 'GET', //Specify the method  
    headers: { //We can define headers too
        'Content-Type': 'MyContentType',
        'Custom-Header': 'Custom Value'
    }
    }, function(error, response, body){
      if(error) {
          console.log(error);
      } else {
          console.log(response.statusCode, body);
      }
});
```

I am using jade instead of HTML. Running the above code outputs the following into my console.

```
200 '[{"id":"4017cd30-164e-11e5-9a6f-f52ee4e229e9","data":{"name":"Hello 
world"}},{"id":"e0591080-1656-11e5-955e-271a38c26f32","data":{"name":"get 
groceries"}},{"id":"e97fe620-1656-11e5-955e-271a38c26f32","data":
{"name":"deposit cheque"}}]'
```

This is what I need to print to webpage. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    request({
    url: url, //URL to hit
    qs: {from: 'blog example', time: +new Date()}, //Query string data
    method: 'GET', //Specify the method  
    headers: { //We can define headers too
        'Content-Type': 'MyContentType',
        'Custom-Header': 'Custom Value'
    }
    }, function(error, response, body){
      if(error) {
          res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: []});
      } else {
          res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: body });
      }

});
```

In you jade file:

```
ul
  for item in data
    li= item
  else
    li sorry, no items!
```

Comment: It is not printing what I want unfortunately. The webpage prints like this:
"
[
{
\
"
i
d
\
"
:
\
"
1
1
f
8
9
5
5
0
-
1
6
4
0
-
1
1
e
5
-
8
6
2
8
-
a
f
4
4
0
2
a
5
c
d
b
4
\
"
,
\
"
d
a
t
a
\
"
:
{
\
"
n
a
m
e
\
"
:
\
"
s
a
m
u
a
l
\
"
,
\
"
c
o
l
o
r
\
"
:
\
"
g
r
e
e
n
\
"
}
}
,
{
\
"
i
d
\
"
:
\
"
1
8
9
7
f
c
c
0
-
1
6
4
0
-
1
1

Printing a newline after every character. I can't show it in the comments.